# Touch a file in objective-c

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I need to update the modification time of a file from a cocoa application. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[Use `NSFileManager`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html)'s [`setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSFileManager_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSFileManager/setAttributes:ofItemAtPath:error:) method with the `NSFileModificationDate` attribute.

*(See the class reference but [also the associated "File System Programming Guide"](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGUide/Introduction/Introduction.html) which is worth reading)*

Comment: That seems to work: "[filemgr setAttributes: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [NSDate date] forKey: NSFileModificationDate] ofItemAtPath: path error: nil]". Thank you!.

Comment: Great :) If my solution fits, don't forget to mark your question as answered by ticking the green mark next to my answer ;)

Comment: Sure!.. sorry I was playing a little more with this stuff xD